# Better way than the ternary condition operator for long terms?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to have a more compact solution for a problem like this??

```
<tr [style.background]="level == 'ALARM' ? 'violet' : level == 'ERROR' ? 'orange' : level == 'WARNING' ? 'yellow' : 'white'">
```

Imaging I would have 10 levels that would be unreadable.

Comment: A pipe would be good here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe solution:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'levelPipe'
})
export class LevelPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        return LevelsMap[value];
    }
}

export const LevelsMap = {
  ALARM: 'violet',
  ERROR: 'orange',
  WARNING: 'yellow',
  OTHER: 'white'
};
```

Usage:

```
<div [style.background]="level | levelPipe">Test</div>
```

Demo: [Demo app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ms2uvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can put all values in object and access color using key properties

**compoment.ts**

```
colorMap = {
'ALARM': 'violet',
'ERROR': 'orange',
'WARNING': 'yellow',
'DEFAULT': 'white'
}
```

**component.html**

```
<tr [style.background]="colorMap[level]">
```

Comment: nice, very smart

Comment: Thanks @ThakurAmit ✌

Answer (score 2):

A simple pipe should do the trick

```
@Pipe({
  name: "mypipe"
  pure: true
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(level: string): string {
    return level == 'ALARM' ? 
    'violet' : level == 'ERROR' ?
    'orange' : level == 'WARNING' ?
    'yellow' : 'white'
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<tr [style.background]="level | mypipe">
```